# Why did css 'position: absolute' stop working?

Tags: css, css-position

In my site, I have a language bar floating on the top right of the screen.

html:

```
<form id='form2' name='form2' method='get' action=''>
<div id='langs' class='langs'>
<button type='submit' name='lang' value='PT'>PT</button>
<button type='submit' name='lang' value='EN'>EN</button>
</div></form>
```

css:

```
.langs {
    background-color: #90A090;
    position:absolute;
    right:4;
    top:4;
}
```

So far so good. But when I updated the website to include a login system from [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL), something went wrong, and the language bar don't float anymore. Instead, it is at the end of the page. There's no css in any file added. And every other aspect of the css still works (like change the background color). The file, that was index.php, is now main.php (index.php is now used for the login screen). The css is all inside the main.php file. What can be causing the change in behavior?

Comment: You should probably give us a link to the webpage and post your whole (relevant) code in a fiddle. We can't see what's causing this by what you've posted.

Comment: did you change the `position` type of any parent elements? if you made any `relative`, then you're going absolute to those, not the document.

Comment: @SteynvanEsveld, since I added lots of files (none with css, though), I still don't know the piece of code that is relevant to this problem. So I can't post it all.

Comment: @MarcB, no other element use position, only this small form. Maybe some javascript is messing with that, but since adding the 'px' units solved my problem, I'm not going to try to find what it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your missing the the units of the value

try:

```
.langs {
    background-color: #90A090;
    position:absolute;
    right:4px; /* right:0; is ok but right:4; will fail */
    top:4px;
}
```

But you are expected to set position relative to the parent, for better results xD

```
form#form2 {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Very strange! It worked, but the units weren't necessary before.

Comment: You have most likely added a `DOCTYPE` declaration in your `HTML`. This is a good thing and prevents the browser from running in quirk mode. One thing it does, is making sure the units are correct. Which wasn't the case.